# Solve for y in sin(y) = cos(y) using a fixed point procedure

Tags: trigonometry, fixed-point-theorems

I'm reading an programming book that uses a lot of math equations and formulas as coding examples. In one lesson, it demonstrates finding the [fixed point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)) for $\sin(x) + \cos(x)$ by repeatedly calling the same function on the function's result until a tolerable answer is found.

$$
f(x) = \cos(x) + \sin(x)
$$
$$
f(f(f(...f(1)))) \iff 1.2587282 \iff \cos(1.2587282) + \sin(1.2587282)
$$

When I plot $y = \sin(x) + \cos(x)$ that is correct.

Another beautiful example was given to demonstrate that the golden ratio 
$φ$ is a fixed point of the translation

$$
f(x) = 1 + 1/x
$$

$$
f(f(f(...f(x)))) \iff 1.618033988 \iff φ
$$

My brain was wandering and I was curious to write my own equation and solve it, but I'm not particularly good at math beyond basic geometry/trigonometry so I got stuck.

I thought, "Ok, let's try to use the fixed point procedure to find the solution for $\sin(x) = \cos(x)$...". I ran into trouble when I tried creating the function for it.

**Can $\sin(x) = \cos(x)$ be represented as a function that can be solved using the fixed point procedure above?**

$$
g(x) = ... ???
$$
$$
g(g(g(...g(1)))) \iff ? \iff \sin(x) \iff \cos(x)
$$

(Yes, I realize that there are an infinite number of fixed points for $\sin(x) = \cos(x)$ but I'm okay with just getting the pair one closest to zero.)

Comment: Finding the intersection of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ would not be a fixed point as per the link you described. What are you asking?

Comment: @naslundx i've rephrased my question. sorry for any confusion

Answer (score 1):

A fixed point $x$ of a function $f$ is one such that $x=f(x)$.

If you want $\sin x = \cos x$, you could try $g_1(x)=\arcsin(\cos x)$ or $g_2(x)=\arccos(\sin x)$. This way, when you solve $x =\arcsin(\cos x)$ you end up with $\sin x = \cos x$ (similarly for the other).

---

Edit: Actually, having plotted $g_1$ and $g_2$, I realized that neither of them would converge under a fixed-point method (the quick/handwaving explanation is that "near" the fixed point, both $g_1$ and $g_2$ are perpendicular to the identity function).

Solving $\sin x=\cos x$ then would be better approached by a (perhaps more general) root-finding procedure on $g(x)=\sin x - \cos x$ instead of the fixed-point approach.

Comment: I want a fixed point where `sin(x)` intersects with `cos(x)`

Answer (score 0):

$\sin x=\cos x \implies tan x=1\implies \tan x=\tan\dfrac{\pi}{4} \implies x=n\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{4}\\$
where $\\ n\in N$

Comment: You should check your solution.

Comment: I understand that a solution can be arrived using such methods. I'm more so looking for a way to represent `sin(x) = cos(x)` as a single function that can be solved using the fixed point procedure outlined in my question.

Comment: i think i've changed $\sin x= \cos x$ into a function $\tan x=1 $